# How do I plot lines joining each pair of centroids of polygons in the `tmap`

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp, tmap

How do I plot lines joining each pairs of centroids of countries in the `tmap`? The color (or transparency) of line should represent the the total population of countries joined.

Example of how map should look is shown in this website - https://jcheshire.com/visualisation/mapping-flows/
But I wish to use tmap

```
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

world

tm_shape(shp = world) +
  tm_polygons(col = "yellow", alpha = 0.70)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it the following way.  First, find all the centroids and convert them to variables `X` and `Y`.

```r
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
w <- world %>% 
  st_centroid() %>% 
  mutate(coords = as.data.frame(st_coordinates(geom))) %>%
  unnest_wider(coords) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(pop))
#> Warning in st_centroid.sf(.): st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over
#> geometries of x
```

Make a blank dataset that has all the undirected pairs of countries

```r
dyads <- expand_grid(c1 = 1:nrow(w), 
                     c2 = 1:nrow(w)) %>% 
  filter(c1 < c2)
dyads <- dyads %>% 
  mutate(iso_a2_a = w$iso_a2[c1], 
         iso_a2_b = w$iso_a2[c2]) %>% 
  select(3:4)
```

Join the data with each side of the dyad.

```r
dyads <- dyads %>% 
  left_join(w %>% select(iso_a2, pop, X, Y) %>% setNames(c("iso_a2_a", "pop_a", "x_a", "y_a")))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(iso_a2_a)`

dyads <- dyads %>% 
  left_join(w %>% select(iso_a2, pop, X, Y) %>% setNames(c("iso_a2_b", "pop_b", "x_b", "y_b")))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(iso_a2_b)`
```

Calculate the total population and the variable `wt` which is the log of total population divided by the max of the log of total population:

```r
dyads <- dyads %>% 
  mutate(tot_pop = pop_a + pop_b, 
         wt = log(tot_pop)/max(log(tot_pop)))
```

Make the plot:

```
ggplot(dyads, aes(x = x_a, xend=x_b, y = y_a, yend=y_b)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(alpha=wt), col="white", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(.001, .025)) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I think, in general, this does the kind of things you want to do, but I'm not sure it's all that illuminating.

The `tmap` line functions want a scalar value of alpha, not one that's mapped to a variable.  As such, it will be difficult to make this work.  Something like this could work, but will make an object that takes a long time to render:

```r
data(World)
coords <- dyads %>% select(4,5,7,8) %>% as.matrix
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(coords), function(i){
  r <- rbind(unname(coords[i,1:2]), unname(coords[i,3:4]))
  st_linestring(r)})
geom <- do.call(st_sfc, lst)
st_geometry(dyads) <- geom

z <- tm_shape(World) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "black") + 
  tm_layout(bg.color="black")
for(i in 1:nrow(dyads)){
  z <- z + 
    tm_shape(dyads[i,]) + 
    tm_lines(alpha=dyads$wt[i]/10, col="white")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but can please use tmap to create the map and also keep world in the background layer.

Comment: @SiH I added a way to do it in `tmap`, but it may not be optimal.